# Query Eureka Server to check if a service is down

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

Is there a possible way to `check if any eureka service is down` ( raise some alert if some service is down for some time > x ) automatically ?

One possible approach is to poll every Eureka service every x minutes and check if they are UP. So is there any other better possible approach supported by eureka without polling externally.

Comment: Disclaimer: I work at codecentric. 
You could use Spring Boot Admin. It can be integrated with Eureka and you have a notifications as a features with multiple ways to notify an administrator if some of the services is down. Take a look at [this](https://piotrminkowski.wordpress.com/2017/06/26/monitoring-microservices-with-spring-boot-admin/) and [this](https://smarttechie.org/2017/06/18/spring-boot-admin-admin-ui-for-administration-of-spring-boot-applications/) blogpost.